# Не удается установить Режим Разработчика Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

Я включил режим разработчика и долго время была загрузка компонентов, она была очень долго. Я решил зайти в "Управление дополнительными компонентами" и увидел что загрузка зависла. Я хотел ее отменить но вылетели настройки. Далее я решил отключить Режим Разработчика в реестре и начал загрузку заново, но загрузка опять  зависла. Я уже перепробывал все, но ничего не  работает.

Upd: В журнале ошибок я понял что это ошибка 0x800F0821